# How to create a self-signed certificate with .pfx and .cer files?

Tags: windows, iis, certificate, self-signed

In IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008, How to create a self-signed certificate with .pfx (containing the private key) and .cer (containing the public key) files?

I used this guideline: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx

and I created the certificate in IIS. When I export it, it only exports the .pfx file, not the .cer file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

Once the self-signed certificate is created in IIS:

1. Select your certificate in IIS under Server Certificates.
2. Click on View.
3. Select the Detail tab.
4. Click the "Copy to File" button.
5. Follow instructions in Certificate Export Wizard to create an X.509 (.CER) certificate.

Comment: If I have self-signed *.pfx certificate I need to manually installed *.cer certificate on client, is it correct? And if I have valid certificate (not self-signed but bought) I don't need *.cer, isn't it?